# Why Youtube-API response in Python contains not all of videos

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have adapted a sample python code i found on the api github page for searching videos for writing all videos related to the search-keyword in a text file. I am using the `nextPageToken` parameter to read through all pages (with `maxResults` set to 50). However it seems that my code can not get all the videos which you can see on youtube (i am also interested in videos which are remotely relevant to my search-keyword). Here is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# 5.3.18

import argparse
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my api key'
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'
YOUTUBE = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

def get_youtube_response(options, next_page_token=None):
    search_response = YOUTUBE.search().list(
        q = options.q,
        type = "video",
        order = options.o,
        pageToken = next_page_token,
        # part = "id, snippet",
        part = "snippet",
        safeSearch = "none",
        videoCaption = "any",
        videoDefinition = "any",
        videoEmbeddable = "any",
        videoLicense = "any",
        videoSyndicated = "any",
        videoType = "any",
        # channelId = None,
        # channelType = "any",
        regionCode = None,
        relevanceLanguage = None,
        maxResults = 50
    ).execute()
    return search_response

def collect_page_vids(youtube_response):
    page = []
    for item in youtube_response.get("items"):
        # if item["id"]["kind"] == 'youtube#video':
        page.append(item.get("snippet").get("title"))
    return page

def collect_all_vids(options):
    all_vids = []
    response = get_youtube_response(options)
    while response.get("nextPageToken"):
        page_vids = collect_page_vids(response)
        all_vids += page_vids   # empty lists can't be added to all_vids
        next_page_token = response.get("nextPageToken")
        print "Next page token: %r" % next_page_token
        response = get_youtube_response(options, next_page_token)
    return all_vids


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--q', help='Search term', default='youtube')
  parser.add_argument('--p', help='Where to save the stuff', default="./youtube.txt")
  parser.add_argument('--o', help='Order', default="relevance")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  try:
    titles = [title.encode("utf8") for title in collect_all_vids(args)]
    with open(args.p, "w") as f:
        for title in titles:
            f.write(title)
            f.write("\n")
    if f.closed:
        print "=" * 21
        print "Finished!"
  except HttpError, e:
    print 'An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

For example searching for the keyword **youtube** i will have only 251 entries written in my text file, which is definitely too little!
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your Python code seems fine. Are you sure that not all videos are listed? If you are signed in when you search via the web UI and you have selected a country and language, YouTube may perform personalization of the result list, based on your interests. At least, try to perform the call again with `regionCode` and `relevanceLanguage` set with the same values as your profile.

Comment: But setting those parameters should restrict the results even more, to the region or language relevant results, right? The question is why using the web UI provide more results than using my code

Comment: I am guessing YouTube optimizes the results based on your preferences. By setting the same language to your code as with the web UI, you will get a more precise picture.

Comment: Setting location and language to US, en (as are in my youtube settings) has brought about 100 more results than having them both None, None or DE, de. But it is still less than the amount that Youtube finds.

Comment: This is very general; YouTube optimizations have given me different outputs for the same input, based on the IP address, logged in account, cookies stored on the browser (or the lack of them), form factor of device, browser user agent and so on. I think that the most precise picture you can get, is by running the same query via the web UI from a browser with its history cleaned, logged in with the **same** account as with the API and having the same settings applied and *then* comparing the results against what the API call brings you.